# How to find the right file with inspector?

Tags: footer

How to find the right file with inspector?

I need to change a link in the footer but I cannot find the right file to change.

The once that I found, `footer.php` has an `echo get_page_link()` but the article doesn't have a number permalink. So I would like to find the right file without the permalink number.

I hope I am clear.